# ¿Cómo funciona el metacaracter \?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo funciona el metacaracter '\' ?

Por ejemplo si hago esto:

```
var a = '\';
document.write(a);
```

no funciona, pero si hago esto:

```
var a = '\\';
document.write(a);
```

Si funciona, he leído que es `"escapar"` , pero  ¿Qué es lo que realmente significa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La barra invertida (denominado carácter de escape) se utiliza para introducir en las cadenas de javascript diferentes elementos que no podrían incluirse de otra manera como pueden ser:

Una comilla simple en una cadena delimitada por comillas simples (`\'`)
Una comilla doble en una cadena delimitada por comillas dobles (`\"`)
Tabuladores, saltos de línea,.... (`\t` `\n`)

Pero entonces ¿cómo introducir una barra invertida en una cadena? Pues utilizando igualmente el carácter de escape: `\\`

```js
console.log('Comilla simple: \'');
console.log("Comilla doble: \"");
console.log('Tabulador\tTexto tabulado');
console.log('Salto de línea\nLínea 2');
console.log('Caracter de escape \\');
```

Comment: agregaria a este ejemplo que no solo javascript usa la barra invertida en tu ejemplo , hay otros lenguajes que comprenden esto la mayoria de los lenguajes nacidos de el respetado **Lenguaje C**